# ¿Cómo filtrar un diccionario json sobre los sentimientos expresados en los números con un filtro para los sentimientos expresados?

Tags: python, json

Tengo una tabla de sentimientos `sentiments` y un diccionario json `content` con puntuaciones sentimentales. Me gustaria filtrar el diccionario en función de lo que esta en la tabla.

`sentiment = ['good','neutral','bad']`. Puede todas ser en la tabla o una parte, depiende.

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "polarity_index": 0,
            "clean_text": "ერთი კითხვა. საზოგადოებაში ბიძინები და ხაზარაძეები არ მოიაზრებიან?",
            "labels": [],
        },
        {
            "polarity_index": -2,
            "clean_text": "       ეს შერცხვებაა",
            "labels": [
                "დასაქმების",
                "პრინციპი",
                "სამუშაო"
            ],
        }
    ],
    "total_items": 6
}
```

Por lo tanto, cómo filtrar el contenido de `contents` para que sólo guarde los elementos que están en la tabla.

Intenté:

```
contents = [content for content in contents if content['polarity_index'] in sentiments]
```

pero no funciona hasta que `content['polarity_index']` es numeros y `sentiments` es string.

```
bad = (-∞, -1], neutral= 0 y good = [2, ∞)
```

Comment: ¿Con qué entero o rango de enteros se corresponderían las categorías `good`, `neutral` y `bad`? Debes establecer una equivalencia para poder filtrar, por ejemplo `good = 1`, `neutral = 0` y `bad = -1` o `good = [1, ∞)`, `neutral= 0` y `bad = (-∞, -1]` o `good = [2, ∞)`, `neutral= [-1, 1]` y `bad = (-∞, -2]` , etc. Si establecer ésto no va a ser posible.

Comment: @FJSevilla Me disculpe, olvidia decirlo. Puesto al dia la pregunta. `bad = (-∞, -1], neutral= 0 y good = [2, ∞)` Pero solo son enteros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma directa de hacerlo, aunque poco escalable es usar simplemente un condicional:

```
sentiment = ["bad", "good"]

filter_items = [
    item for item in contents["items"]
    if ("good" in sentiment and item["polarity_index"] >= 1) or
       ("neutral" in sentiment and item["polarity_index"] == 0) or 
       ("bad" in sentiment and item["polarity_index"] <= -1)
       ]
```

Si queremos algo más escalable, que nos permita trabajar con más intervalos sin complicarnos demasiado, no hay algo preconstruido que nos permita de forma simple representar un intervalo (en algunos casos `range` puede ser útil), pero por comodidad podemos implementar una minúscula clase que nos permita representarlo, así como comprobar si un valor está o no en él:

```
class Interval:
    def __init__(self, lower=float("-inf"), upper=float("inf")):
        self.lower = lower
        self.upper = upper

    def __contains__(self, item):
        return self.lower <= item <= self.upper
```

Una vez que tenemos ésto, debemos crear un diccionario para mapear cada variable categórica a un intervalo:

```
sentiment_map = {
    "good": Interval(lower=1),
    "neutral": Interval(lower=0, upper=0),
    "bad": Interval(upper=-1)
    }
```

Con ésto, ya podemos usar una lista por compresión para filtrar los items de forma simple:

```
class Interval:
    def __init__(self, lower=float("-inf"), upper=float("inf")):
        self.lower = lower
        self.upper = upper

    def __contains__(self, item):
        return self.lower <= item <= self.upper

sentiment_map = {
    "good": Interval(lower=1),
    "neutral": Interval(lower=0, upper=0),
    "bad": Interval(upper=-1)
    }

contents = {
    "items": [
        {
            "polarity_index": 0,
            "clean_text": "ერთი კითხვა. საზოგადოებაში ბიძინები და ხაზარაძეები არ მოიაზრებიან?",
            "labels": [],
        },
        {
            "polarity_index": -2,
            "clean_text": "       ეს შერცხვებაა",
            "labels": [
                "დასაქმების",
                "პრინციპი",
                "სამუშაო"
            ],
        },
        {
            "polarity_index": 45,
            "clean_text": "       საზოგადოებაში",
            "labels": [
                "დასაქმების",
                "პრინციპი",
                "სამუშაო"
            ],
        }
    ],
    "total_items": 6
}
```

---

```
sentiment = ['good', 'bad']
filter_intervals = [
        sentiment_map[sent] for sent in sentiment if sent in sentiment_map]
filter_items = [item for item in contents["items"] 
                if any(item["polarity_index"] in interval
                       for interval in filter_intervals)]
```

> ```
> >>> filter_items
>
> [{'polarity_index': -2, 'clean_text': '       ეს შერცხვებაა', 'labels': ['დასაქმების', 'პრინციპი', 'სამუშაო']},
>  {'polarity_index': 45, 'clean_text': '       საზოგადოებაში', 'labels': ['დასაქმების', 'პრინციპი', 'სამუშაო']}]
> ```

```
sentiment = ['good', 'neutral']
filter_intervals = [
        sentiment_map[sent] for sent in sentiment if sent in sentiment_map]

filter_items = [item for item in contents["items"] 
                if any(item["polarity_index"] in interval
                       for interval in filter_intervals)]
```

> ```
> >>> filter_items
>
> [{'polarity_index': 0, 'clean_text': 'ერთი კითხვა. საზოგადოებაში ბიძინები და ხაზარაძეები არ მოიაზრებიან?', 'labels': []},
>  {'polarity_index': 45, 'clean_text': '       საზოგადოებაში', 'labels': ['დასაქმების', 'პრინციპი', 'სამუშაო']}]
> ```